# Google map API - AutoSuggest form textfield

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the code below. I try to create a map with a marker and an InfoWindow in which I would like to have a textfield to write an address and get the direction from that address to marker. I would like, when you write an address in the text field appear above suggested places from google. I hope that I explain nice my problem and someone help me.

```
var geocoder;
var directionsService;
var directionsDisplay;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.396746, 21.677257);   
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:"<center><strong>Apollo Camping</strong></center><br/>"+ 
                "<center>Πως θα έρθετε</center>"+ 
                "Διεύθυνση: <input id='clientAddress' type='text' onFocus='geolocate()' placeholder='Εισάγετε τη διεύθυνσή σας' size=22>"+
                "<center><input type='button' onClick=getDir() value='Λήψη οδηγιών'></center>"
    });

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}; 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Atlanta/Sandy Springs',
    clickable: true
});



    infowindow.open(map, marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
});
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: false
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));



}

function getDir() {
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': document.getElementById('clientAddress').value
},

function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var origin = results[0].geometry.location;
        var destination = latlng;

        var request = {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

    } else {
        document.getElementById('clientAddress').value =
            "Directions cannot be computed at this time.";
    }
});
}
initialize();
```

This is the javascript and I call it in the html with .
I'm waiting your reply and I hope that somebody can understand what I mean.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: @Dr.Molle thank you for you reply. I know how to create an autocomplete textfield that is in the html body. But I don't know how to create an autocomplete textfield in the infoWindow as you see in my code above the textfield clientAddress.

Comment: create the autocomplete when the domready-event of the infowindow fires

Comment: @Dr.Molle I'm sorry but I can't understand what you exactly mean. Could you help me a bit more please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the focus-listener from the `#clientAddress`
2. create the autocomplete on domready of the infowindow:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready',function(){
    //create the autocomplete
    var ac=new google.maps.places
           .Autocomplete(document.getElementById('clientAddress'));
    //run getDir when the place changes
    google.maps.event.addListener(ac, 'place_changed', getDir);

   });
   ```

Comment: I tried it but sometime it work and other not. I saw that the problem is with the order that the code execute, because when I open the infowindow by myself it work fine, unlike when the infowindow open itself.

Comment: I solve the problem with a delay for infowindow.open(map, marker);